# How to hide active program from top bar in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome

I was wondering could I hide running application from the top bar in Ubuntu.

This is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: the active program i mean is that firefox web browser name on top

Answer (score 7):

The below command can hide it on call;

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.appMenu.hide();'
```

to show it back, use below command.

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.appMenu.show();'
```

Comment: Would this persist through reboot?

Comment: Yes if the command added to startup applications